# Cordova plugin - How to use build.json

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

i want to change the build config preferences in my Xcode Project from a cordova plugin (im developing a cordova plugin).
I specifically need to modify this preference AlwaysEmbedSwiftStandardLibraries = "YES". 
I tried to do it using the build.json file but it didn't work.
This is the build.json file which is located in the root folder the same one in which plugin.xml is located

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "buildFlag": [
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES"
            ]
        },
        "release": {
          "buildFlag": [
              "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to build the application with `--buildConfig` option

```
cordova build ios --prod --device --buildConfig
```

Comment: it does the job, but. Isn't there an automatic way?

Comment: Sorry for necro but, this doesn't really answer the question. After all how is a plugin suppose to ensure that people using the plugin builds the ios platform with the --buildConfig flag?

Comment: @Tyler having build config in plugin may end up with clashes when there are multiple plugin doing same things. So ideally the config file has to be at project level only. The plugins should only enforce the consumer to add these config in project's json file and Cordova honours this json only when --buildConfig param is passed..